# Create shadow on transparent view - react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have to cast shadows from a transparent view with absolute position/dimensions, but can't seem to be able to do that. The whole structure from top to bottom:

- Some text overlaying the transparent view
- Transparent view with shadow
- Other stuff to be displayed underneath

If I define the background color of the view to be 'transparent', the shadow will then be applied to its child elements, in this case the text overlaying. If I define the background color to be a solid one, the other stuff to be displayed underneath will be blocked.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I've done some experiments and this is so weird: the shadow of the child elements or the view itself seems to be based on the transparency of the alpha channel of that view. If I put a non-completely transparent background there, or even nest a dummy view into it and make it transparent via `opacity`, the shadow casted from the view is still not the fully what I specified - it's kind of like sharing the shadow sum with its child elements....

Any workaround would be appreciated!! This behavior is driving me crazy.

I was trying to create shadow with this style:

```
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 1
},
shadowRadius: 4,
shadowOpacity: 1
```

Another edit: I used a transparent Image as background, it also doesn't work :(

Comment: Show your code for creating shadow

Comment: Added! :) @RutvikBhatt

Comment: I think using elevation in your styles would work

Comment: @Craques I read that `elevation` is Android only :( Is there a cross platform way?

Comment: @John I use a windows machine, have not developed for ios yet was thinking that may help.

Comment: The view gotta have a color to be able to cast a shadow.. Try adding a color with opacity of 99%, see if it helps. Otherwise sounds like you can use `textShadow` instead: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

Comment: @HedeH Thanks for the thoughts. I tried adding a BG color with opacity, there was indeed shadow casted by the View, but not the amount I specified. Even weirder is that the child elements also shadow - seems that RN shifts the rest of the shadow to the child elements....

Comment: ShadowOffset. color, radius etc will work on iOS only. Android shadows work with elevation. To make shadows work on both you have to use elevation and shadow properties. Shadow properties will be ignored on android and elevation will be ignored on iOS. Unfortunately on android you cannot edit the shadow cast by using elevation.
[Shadow props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props)
[View style props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props#elevation)

Comment: @NemiShah You are right :( Didn't debug on Android and now I see there's no shadow there.

Comment: We opted for a different design in the end but I will leave this question here in case someone comes by with a solution that might be helpful for those who do need to implement this shadow